# Ropes and Pulleys - Really unintuitive answer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

I usually don't want to do this, but please go to this link, the solution is too big to post it here

http://engineering.union.edu/~curreyj/MER-201_files/Exam2_2_26_09_Solution.pdf

And go to page 5 of the pdf.

Briefly, the problem say

> Determine the velocity of the 60-lb block A if the
>   two blocks are released from rest and the 40-lb block B
>   moves 2 ft up the incline. The coefficient of kinetic friction
>   between both blocks and the inclined planes is $\mu_k$ = 0.10.

**Things I am confused with the solution**

1.First of all, I seriously thought lb was mass not force. after some googling, it turns out they are used interchangeably...

2.Where did they even get $2s_a + s_b = 0$ from? Why did they determine the change in distance this way? My first assumption was that if block B moved up 2ft, then block A should move down 2ft (the rope must "move" 2ft too right?). Then I wasn't sure, so I did a few triangles and found that the angle made a difference

3.Where did $2v_A = -v_B$ come from?

4 The FBD for block A is confusing, why is the friction force $F_A$ in the direction of the ropes? I thought it was block B that is going down? Am I the only one who had trouble deducting that the pulley and block A are the same object?

5.Look at the final answer, how could $v_b$ be negative? The problem says block B goes UP.

If you are wondering, this is not homework. I am just interested in this problem and it is out of curiosity and very confused with the concepts.

I've had at most introductory physics experience, but I think I should have been able to solve this still.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"2.Where did they even get 2sa+sb=0 from?"
From the assumption that the length of the rope does not change.
"Why did they determine the change in distance this way? My first assumption was that if block B moved up 2ft, then block A should move down 2ft (the rope must "move" 2ft too right?)."
No, there is a difference between a movable pulley and a fixed pulley, so A moves down 1 ft.

"3.Where did 2vA=−vB come from?"
From the same assumption as above. However, the direction of vA is shown incorrectly (or, alternatively, the signs in the formula are wrong).

"4 The FBD for block A is confusing, why is the friction force FA in the direction of the ropes? I thought it was block B that is going down?"
It is writen in the statement of the problem that block B went up.
" Am I the only one who had trouble deducting that the pulley and block A are the same object?"
I don't quite understand what this phrase means exactly and how it is relevant.

"5.Look at the final answer, how could vb be negative? The problem says block B goes UP."

See the answer to your item 3.

Comment: @Akhmetli, for 3) (and 5), you mean in the key right? That's what I am confused too. Forget 4), block A is going down, so it make sense for the friction to be in the direction of the ropes

Comment: @jak: I mean in FBD for block A - I guess this is the only place where they show the direction of vA.

Comment: Just one last thing, so the numerical answers is right, but just the signs are wrong? Sorry for being repetitive

Comment: @jak: Sorry, don't have time to check the solution.

Comment: Oh it's fine. Is it possible to solve this without knowing what is "mechanical advantage"

Comment: @jak: Sure, as I said, you just use the assumption that the length of the rope does not change, so when one meter of rope passes the fixed pulley, the movable pulley moves by 0.5 meter.

Answer (score 1):

2 - the block 'A' is on a pulley, when it moves 1 ft the rope moves 2ft.  It has a 2:1 mechanical advantage, normally you would use this to move block 'A' half the distance you pull the rope and with twice the force - the point of a pulley is to use a smaller force for a longer distance.

Comment: sorry, I'll look up this "mechanical advantage" stuff on my own. Don't know why I expected you to explain everything to me.

Comment: Do you mind if I bug you once more? Without knowing "mechanical advantage" could I have solved this?

Comment: @jak - you don't have to know the word, but you do have to knowhow pulleyswork

Comment: I never learn the concept, but is it just something you could see "oh B moves 2ft up, so A must go down 2ft!". I have difficulties wrapping my heads around this

Comment: @jak if B goes down 2ft then the rope must move 2ft. If the rope on A's side gets 2ft shorter than the block can only move 1ft - because the rope is doubled by the pulley. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_and_tackle#More_on_mechanical_advantage

Comment: Okay I just reaad some of these on my own and I think I have some intuition now. Though it seemed that this only holds because the friction coefficient is the same on both sides. Is it wrong to assume that we don't know what will happen if the coefficient of friction is different? Also, based on the equation they have $2s_a + s_b = 0$, this implies that the weights have NOTHING to do with the rope problem